# RestKit 0.20 mapping trouble (using JSON from API)

Tags: ios, json, api, restkit

I can pull in the `springs` **name**, but can't pull in the `leafs` **abbreviation** correctly.

Can you help?  Will post any extra code as needed.  Thanks!

API JSON

```
{
    "springs": [{
        "name": "daff",
        "links": {
            "api": {
                "springs": {
                    "href": "http://api.xxx.com/v1/springs/daff"
                },
            }
        },
        "leafs": [{
            "name": "raff",
            "abbreviation": "rf",
            "season": {
                "year": 2014,
            },
        },
```

ViewController.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *venues;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *venuesLeafs;

- (void)configureRestKit
{
// initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
      NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.xxx.com"];
      AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

      // initialize RestKit
      RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

      // setup object mappings
      RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
      [venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];

      RKObjectMapping *venuevenueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[VenueVenue class]];
      [venuevenueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"abbreviation": @"abbreviation"}]; 

      [venueMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"abbreviation" toKeyPath:@"abbreviation" withMapping:venuevenueMapping]];

      // register mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
      RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
      [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                              pathPattern:nil
                                                  keyPath:@"springs"  
                                              statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];


          [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return venues.count;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      Venue *venue = [venues objectAtIndex:section];
      return venue.name;
}


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Venue *venue = [venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
          VenueVenue *venuevenue = [venuesLeafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          cell.textLabel.text = venuevenue.abbreviation;

        return cell;
    }
```

Seems to not be adding the property mapping to **abbreviation** correctly.

UPDATE: Adding headers per request

Venue.h

```
#import "VenueVenue.h"

@interface Venue : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) VenueVenue *venueVenue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *leagues;

@end
```

VenueVenue.h

```
@interface VenueVenue : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *abbreviation;

@end
```

Comment: Are you looking for "leafs" inside the object/dictionary that's inside the array that's inside "springs"?  (I have no idea how RestKit works, but I suspect it's evil.)

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Well, if you used NSJSONSerialization it would be right there -- `[@springs][0][@"leafs"][0][@"abbreviation"]`.  (Don't overlook that "leafs" is an array containing an object/dictionary.)

Comment: Is part of what your saying that I should be using `addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"abbreviation"]];` instead of `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"abbreviation": @"abbreviation"}];`?

Comment: I haven't the foggiest -- I haven't tried to crack your code.  But the JSON is object/array/object/array/object  (`{[{[{`) to get to where "abbreviation" is.

Comment: Let me say it's unclear why you're using RestKit parsing vs plain NSJSONSerialization parsing to NSArrays and NSDictionarys.  You're not saving any logic, from what I can see, and it's much more obscure.

Comment: Are you asking if I'm saving any data in the app, that you're unaware of?

Comment: Not asking anything -- just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"abbreviation" toKeyPath:@"abbreviation"
```

to

```
relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"leafs" toKeyPath:@"venueVenues"
```

Because the array content in the response that equates to your desired relationship content is under the 'leafs' key, not the inner 'abbreviation' key.

And change this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) VenueVenue *venueVenue;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *venueVenues;
```

---

For your table view I expect something like:

You should have an array of venues. The number of sections should be the `count` of venues.

For each section, you can have a header to show the venue details and the number of rows is the `count` of `venues.venueVenues` (though you should really rename the `VenueVenue` class and property name).

In the delegate methods you get the venue with `venue = self.venues[indexPath.section]` and then, for the rows, `venueVenue = venue.venueVenues[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Will change.  So then don't add an extra RKResponseDescriptor for this, leave it as is?  Just wondering if I need to add `RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorLeafs =
      [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venuevenueMapping
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                              pathPattern:nil
                                                  keyPath:@"leafs"
                                              statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];` or anything

Comment: Also in my `RKObjectMapping *venuevenueMapping` do I need to use `addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"abbreviation"]];` instead of `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"abbreviation": @"abbreviation"}];`?

Comment: That response descriptor would never match anything (you can't index into the springs array). The mappings are identical, the array method is just the short form version.

Comment: Just got a crash when I did that `reason: '[<Venue 0xa2e3150> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key abbreviation.'`  Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't crash unless if I have any word other than `leafs` in there, if that helps

Comment: Because it was never used till you corrected that. Add your class headers to the question - what is the relationship property called?

Comment: Added my Classes, is that what you were needing?  Let me know if not.

Comment: Im trying to set breakpoints to figure out where its happening and still can't tell if its somewhere in my `configureRestKit` method, or in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Well, `_venues` and `venuesLeagues` usage in table methods looks wrong

Comment: Ya I'm almost positive whatever I have for the `cellForIndexPath` is not quite right.  Do you have a suggestion from what you see, that I should change it to?  Or what exactly I'm missing or doing wrong on it?

Comment: I'd expect you to use sections for the venues and rows in each section for the 'venuevenues' (which seems like a strange name)

Comment: Ya its a super weird name.  I'm not totally sure what you were saying there, can you say it a different way?  Also, I just updated my code a second ago with something I was trying, let me know if its what your getting at.

Comment: Its still crashing, but I updated the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, does that look good for that part?

Comment: Per your updated response regarding the `tableView` parts, "You should have an array of venues. The number of sections should be the count of venues.", I have: `return venues.count;`

Comment: For "For each section, you can have a header to show the venue details and the number of rows is the count of venues.venueVenues" I'm not totally sure what your saying I should do different specifically.

Comment: For "In the delegate methods you get the venue with venue = self.venues[indexPath.section] and then, for the rows, venueVenue = venue.venueVenues[indexPath.row]" I'm wondering if you could help me suss that out a little bit more.

Comment: Yoooooo!  I finally got it!